# "Self-assured" vs. "self-confident"

Tags: meaning, differences, adjectives

Are there any differences between the words *self-assured* and *self-confident*?

Comment: Subtle, but *self-assured* may have negative connotations; *self-confident* is almost always positive (negative could be *over-confident*).

Comment: According to OED, they are exact synonyms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where self-assured is 'sure of yourself,' relates to you and your actions (it also comes with a minor connotation of pride), self-confident is confidence in one's abilities and relates more to your mind.

They may be used interchangeably, (m-w.com defines self-assured *as* self-confident), but there are minor differences in tone that can affect your reader.

Answer (score 1):

Self-assurance can sometimes make you give yourself too much credit, which, if you're not careful, can touch pride

However, with self-confidence, you don't have to give yourself credit, because you know your own strengths and abilities, so you've already got enough