# A word for believing that oneself if good enough, being self-satisfied?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am after a single word (or maybe two), for when one is satisfied within themself, is confident and feels as though they are good enough, not doubting their ability in any way.

> I am _________. I don't need external validation.

However, I need a word that does not have an overly negative connotation, like 'arrogant', and also isn't comparative, like 'superior'.

Comment: Possibly answered here https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/83963/self-assured-vs-self-confident

Comment: Self-assured, self-confident, as discussed in the question cited.

Answer (score 1):

Being 'Complacent' means to be 'Self-Satisfied'

To elaborate--

It means, I am overtly happy with the way I am, and do not feel critical of myself.

Comment: [Complacent](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/complacent) (OED source) has a negative connotation. It is often used close in meaning to "sufficiently happy about the status quo", implying that this is the cause of why you won't catch a new problem. That connotation makes it less suitable for the OP's purposes, who explicitly wants to avoid negative connotations.